# How to apply for german transit visa?

Tags: schengen, germany, transit-visas

I have a transit at Frankfurt en route to India. It looks like I need transit visa at Frankfurt (my H1B visa on passport expired, I only have valid I-797).
How can I apply for German(or Schengen) transit visa?
Can I apply that at airport on arrival?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a visa to transit in the Schengen area?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: It might be considered a duplicate, but that question really doesn't cover this particular scenario very well; airside transit rules are not entirely harmonized among the Schengen states.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelHampton, the question is whether a visa is needed, but how to apply for it.

Answer (score 2):

You should not need an airport transit visa from Germany for this itinerary.

The German mission in the US explicitly says that you are [exempt from the airport transit visa requirement](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html) if:

> 2. If they return from the USA after having used the visa

Further, Timatic, the system which airlines will check to determine if your documents are in order, [notes the same exception](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&NA=IN&EM=US&DE=IN&TR=DE&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C).

> - returning from Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania, USA or United Kingdom after having used the visa and traveling to any non-Schengen Member State;

Notably, it is not required for your US visa to be valid when you are *departing* the US, nor is it required for your visa to have only recently expired.

You may wish to bring printed copies of both the Timatic output and the information from the German mission when you check in for your flight.